# AWS cloudfront integration issue

Tags: magento2, aws, integration, cdn, cloudfront-cdn

I have setup the AWS CloudFront cdn on my magento dev instance.
Everything is working correctly but html and json files are not loading from cdn. I am getting CORS issue

[image]

Please help me if you know the solution